# How to print a deque from the end?

Tags: c++, c++11, deque

Question is quite simple, how do I print a deque, but from behind. Example: I have a deque with elements {5,4,3,2,1}. I want to print that deque, but starting from the last element, so I should have someting like 1 2 3 4 5 on my screen.

Usual `for(int i(deque.size()); i > 0; i--)` loop obviously won't work.
Little intro to the program. It finds numbers whose sum is even or odd, and sorts them into two different deques that are to be printed on screen.
This is the code that works for 'usual' printing. But my task says to print them backwards.
Oh, and the elements are added to the deque using push_front function. And no, I'm not allowed to use push_back to 'fix' it.

```
void PrintDek(Dek v4) {
for (int i(0); i < v4.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << v4[i];
    if (i != v4.size() - 1) std::cout << ",";
}
}
```

If some of you feel the need for the whole program's code, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Please show your attempt and how it doesn't work.

Comment: why does the the `for(int i(deque.size()); i > 0; i--)` doesn't work?

Comment: Lack of sleep or simple lack of knowledge, it should have been `deque.size()-1` and it would have worked. That actually fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after seeing my code after a good few hours of sleep (this question was posted after 2AM according to my timezone), I've come to realize what my mistake was. By using `deque.size()` and moving all the way up to the value that the `size()` function returns, I was actually going out of range, accessing forbidden parts of memory. 
Simple `deque.size()-1` now works. So the loop would look like this `for(int i(deque.size()-1); i >= 0; i--)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [reverse iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/rbegin.

```
for(auto iter = deque.rbegin(); iter != deque.rend(); ++iter) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: How do I print in the manner I used above, as `deque[i]`. I get this error message Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0349 no operator "[]" matches these operands Zadatak 4 c:\Users\HARI 256 SSD 8GB\Documents\TP Tutorijali\Tutorijal 3\Zadatak 4\Zadatak 4\Zadatak 4.cpp 55

Comment: @Rose Print `*iter`.

Comment: @Rose When using iterators, call the overloaded `*` operator to get the value. For your case, do `std::cout << *iter;`. Please read about iterators at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator.